# How to show rigorously that this integral goes to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

How do I rigorously show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{1+x^{2}} dx$ goes to $0$. I managed to show that it converges by using the fact $\sin{x}$ is bounded and that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} dx$ goes to $\pi$. Any hints/suggestions would be appreciated. This is from a real analysis course.

Comment: Hint: the integrand is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}$. Then $$f(-x) = \frac{\sin(-x)}{1+(-x)^2} = -\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, so 
$$
\int_{-M}^M f(x)\ \mathsf dx = 0
$$
for any $M>0$. Taking the limit as $M\to\infty$ yields the result.